# dojo: multipleDefine error with qwest.js

Tags: javascript, dojo, require, amd, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to load `qwest.js` using the dojo (ArcGIS) AMD loader but am getting a `multipleDefine` error.

```
require([
  // `../vendor/react/react.js`, // this works fine
  `../vendor/qwest/qwest.min.js`, // this causes error
], (
 // React,
    qwest,
) => { ... })
```

At first I thought it was because I added it as a package in the dojo config object, but doing this throws the exact same error.

Config:

```
  require({
    async: true
  , parseOnLoad: true
  , packages: [{
      name: `app`
    , location: `${location.pathname}js`
    , main: `main`
    }]
  }, [`app`])
```

Comment: May I ask you why you want to use Qwest ? Dojo does support `XmlHttpRequest2` special data like `ArrayBuffer`, `Blob` and `FormData`. Dojo is also based on `Promise`... Why not using `dojo/request` ?

Comment: @ben Not a particularly good reason, I had some qwest calls in my codebase from before, but this became a more generalized question about AMD and `multipleDefine`. I guess I'll try it with vanilla Dojo (not the ArcGIS unminified version) to be able to debug further.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know why you get that error but you can workaround it by letting `qwest` thinking commonjs should be used instead of amd:

```js
//for testing purpose
require({
   packages: [{ name: 'pyrsmk', location: 'https://rawgit.com/pyrsmk'}]
});


//the trick is to let qwest think you use commonjs instead of amd
window.module = {};
require(['pyrsmk/qwest/master/build/qwest.min'], function(qwest) {
  qwest = module.exports;   
  delete window.module;
  
  console.log(qwest);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dojo/dojo/1.10/dojo.js"></script>
```